# выход из вертикального слайдера

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, fullpage

Как организовать выход и вход из вертикального слайдера (fullpage.js)?
Вот ссылка на плагин http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/.

Смысл в том, что сам плагин располагается посередине страницы, и нужно сделать так, чтобы пользователь смог спокойно прокручивать всю страницу, а при достижении слайдера прокрутка происходила бы уже слайдами, после последнего слайда возвращала на место после слайда и вверх также.

Я так понял, нужно включать стандартное поведение скроллу в нужный момент и выходить из функции.

Comment: Недавно проскакивал похожий вопрос. Посмотрите, может поможет: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/481737/186112

Comment: у меня как раз проблема с выходом из функции, т.е. алгоритм то я понял но как реализовать нет...

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все намного проще)

Вам нужно при инициализации указать опцию "scrollOverflow: true" :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#fullpage').fullpage({
        ...
        scrollOverflow: true
    });
});
```

и подключить библиотеку "jquery.slimscroll.min" :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendors/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.fullPage.js"></script>
```

Офф док:

> scrollOverflow: (default false) defines whether or not to create a
>   scroll for the section in case its content is bigger than the height
>   of it. When set to true, your content will be wrapped by the plugin.
>   Consider using delegation or load your other scripts in the
>   afterRender callback. In case of setting it to true, it requires the
>   vendor plugin jquery.slimscroll.min and it should be loaded before the
>   fullPage.js plugin. For example:

[Пример](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/scrolling.html#firstPage)

Comment: Вы мой спаситель.Я так понял нужно все обернуть в секции слайда. т.е верхняя часть страницы 1 слайд, потом идет сам слайдер и потом нижняя часть тоже как слайд.Может подскажете тогда как еще 2 нюанса побороть?1 этот плагин перекрывает плагин плавной прокрутки, есть ли для него какие нибудь настройки плавности?2.у слайдера должна быть навигация а при таком методе навигация появляется у все странице, можно сделать навигацию отдельным элементам?

Comment: 1. как первый плагин, так и второй вешают слушателя на событие сколла(колесико мышки) и дабы добиться желаемого результата нужно лезть под капот плагинов и настраивать слушателя.

Comment: @AlexanderMyravjev 2. Создавайте свои элементы и вешайте на них слушателя "onclick" при котором будет вызываться метод "moveTo(section, slide)" с указанной нужной секции и слайда.